# Cross domain Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

While calling MVC webservice from my html page  it was always going to error; please help me

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(Response.ErrorMessage )
    },
    error: function (e, status) {
        alert(e + " Fail " + status)
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `dataType : "jsonp"` ?
which error message you get?

Comment: you don't need `crossDomain: true,` or `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: Start by opening your **javascript debugging console** and looking for error messages. Next, still within your **javascript debugging console**, look at the network requests that took place to see if your server returned what you expected it to.

Comment: yes i tried Jsonp  and callback also

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup CORS (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) or use JSONP. If you decide to use JSONP then you have to send proper callback function name with JSON data.

Comment: To complement this answer: If you want to use JSONP, please also have a look at the possible [security concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Security_concerns) of it...

Comment: Yea, you should use CORS if it is viable option for you.